# Which Python Conditional Return Statement Is The Most Pythonic?

Tags: python, function, return, conditional-statements, conventions

Which of the following is the proper way to return something with Python when using conditionals? Does it matter? And why?

```
# OPTION 1
if conditional:
    return a
else:
    return b


# OPTION 2
if conditional:
    return a
return b
```

Comment: the else is redundant

Comment: Im not sure you understand what syntactically correct means .. or your teacher may not

Comment: Technically they are both syntactically valid.

Comment: Both are perfectly valid and likely to produce indentical p-code. If `conditional` is a real boolean expression (not just one of different type interpreted as boolean), then `return condition` would be clearer, though probably also identical output.

Comment: I fixed the Question title, I meant which is the most Pythonic, or the best practice way of doing it.

Comment: I prefer to have the else statement as it makes is more explicit that it returns b if condition is not met. Especially if there is more code before the "return b" then it might be easy to miss the first "shortcutting" return statement.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The *proper* Python way would be:

```
return conditional
```

["Simple is better than complex"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) remember? :)

---

Regarding your edited question, I would use `# OPTION 2` because ["Flat is better than nested."](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and this solution saves an indentation level.  You'll appreciate this when:

```
return b
```

is actually something like:

```
return very_long_and_unwieldy_name_that_you_cannot_change
```

Besides, the `else:` in this case is unnecessary (both syntactically as well as visually) and redundant; it simply wastes space.

That said, you may want to consider using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) instead:

```
return a if conditional else b
```

This is a very concise and elegant alternative when `a`, `conditional`, and `b` are all nice and short.

Comment: +10000000000000 if I could ... this is an awful pattern(in OP) that I see all the time

Comment: If `conditional` doesn't yield a strict Boolean value and you want that, then `return bool(conditional)`

Comment: Assumes that `conditional` is a boolean expression. If it's an expression that returns a non-boolean value that will be interpreted as boolean, then the OP's construction (either of them) is necessary.

Comment: @Sneftel: If you explicitly want less information, you should return less information. You might as well ask why `bool` itself throws away that information. kindall's comment is just pointing out that you have the choice of doing it if you want to, without any need to extra complexity as in the OP's code.

Comment: Good suggestion for n00bs. Assume that the conditional statements had more to them, and the boolean part of this question was just to make the question clean. I've fixed it.

Comment: @JoranBeasley what is an awful pattern?

Comment: `if some_true_thing: return True`

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a trick question. The first one is *not* syntactically correct:

```
if conditional:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

In Python, an `else` clause, like anything else that introduces a suite, has to end in a `:` character.

If you fix that, then they're both syntactically valid, and both semantically meaningful. In fact, they mean the same thing. They'll even compile to almost the same code, except that the first one might cause Python to generate some extra code for a third "fall off the end of the function" case that never gets called.

But, as [iCodez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26725294/908494) explains, both of these are an anti-pattern; just `return conditional`, or `return bool(conditional)`, as appropriate.

Note that even in the case where evaluating `conditional` raises an exception, the different possibilities are *still* all equivalent (up to the contents of the traceback)—they'll all just raise that exception.